# Double quote escape is giving Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )

Tags: javascript

I Have an issue where user last name(adfs2"k) which has double quote, whenever I need to edit the last name and click on a button, it throws an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

I have tried the double quote escape, but it still throws

```
lastName = lastName.replace(/\"/g,"\\\"");
```

and this is the function, i'm using

```
"javascript:editUserEmailPopup(' + "'" + firstName + "'" + ',' + "'" + lastName + "'" + ');"
```

Comment: This is one of the many reasons **not** to embed function calls in HTML attributes. Consider using [modern event handling instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

As [@T.J. Crowder suggests in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71236630/#comment125918748_71236630), one cause of this issue is embedding your function call within an HTML attribute. Using these inline-event-handlers can lead to problems like this as well as unmanageable code. The alternative is to use an external script tag, or to inline a script tag.

However, even within an isolated script, this code has some issues that make it unclear what it should even do and does not work. I believe the code is meant to return the `firstName` variable surrounded by double quotes, followed by the `lastName` variable surrounded by single quotes. The code is unclear but this solution should be able to fix it:

```js
const firstName = 'asd5"3'
const lastName = "jfni8'543"
console.log(`"${firstName}", '${lastName}'`)
```

This syntax of embedding variables into strings and being able to use double quotes and single quotes without escaping them is called [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

> Template literals are enclosed by the backtick ( ) (grave accent) character instead of double or single quotes.
> Template literals can contain placeholders. These are indicated by the dollar sign and curly braces (`${expression}`). The expressions in the placeholders and the text between the backticks ( ) get passed to a function.
> (From MDN)